# Integrating Eclipse's local history with Time Machine (Mac)

Tags: eclipse, macos, timemachine

Eclipse has the very nifty "Compare with Local History" feature which lets you compare all files in the workspace against previous revisions. This is very useful to recover older versions even when they are not in a source control system, and it works because Eclipse keeps snapshots of all files when you save them.

Eclipse (by default) keeps up to one week, up to fifty changes and up to 1 MB of snapshot data per file.

On a Mac, you also have the Time Machine backups, which snapshot every file once per hour, keeping hourly snapshots for a day, daily snapshots for a month, and weekly snapshots until you run out of disk space.

Is there an Eclipse plugin to make use of the Time Machine data for local history beyond the copies that Eclipse stores?

Comment: Why not use a version control system. Git in particular doesn't need a central repository so you can initialize a local repository for each project.

Answer (score 1):

No there doesn't seem to be, and there are relatively few mac-specific plugins. Your choices are basically to use the built-in functionality to restore your whole workspace (pain) or use the built-in functionality as is.

This is similar to the choices you'd have for VMWare snapshots.

Comment: Yeah, I guess that's how it is. At least the data is still there, even though it is a bit bothersome to get it. I really wish Time Machine was more popular and supported better by other applications. If not in Eclipse, then maybe a Mac-native text editor which delves down into the archives. Follow-up question on Superuser: http://superuser.com/questions/155319/applications-with-time-machine-integration

Comment: Well, in many cases it would be nice if Time machine interfaced elegantly with something like SVN or git working copies. Hope the answer was helpful though.

Answer (score 0):

Well the local history of eclipse is stored in the .metadata directory of your workspace, so technically you could go back to a former version of your whole workspace with the Time Machine. Not sure if that's what you really want, though.

However the amount that eclipse stores is configurable in the preferences. So I suggest you just pick whatever you feel you need there.